# Extract string between 2 characters; differing format

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple cells some with spaces [ 12345 ] and some without [12345]; i have the spaces coded in, but i need to add a line extracts the text without the spaces. Is this possible to perform in the same script

```
Sub ExtractText()

Range ("X3").Select
ActiveCell.ForumulaR1C1 
    "=MID(RC[-23],FIND(""[ "",RC[-23])+2,FIND('' ]"",RC[-23])-FIND(''['',RC[-23])-2)"
Range ("X4").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I feel like I need an IF/THEN statement in there

Comment: Im extracting the text to a new cell, the code i have with spaces works fine, but I am looking to add code without spaces in the same script

Comment: Hi B.Cole.  Good question - what you're looking for is definitely possible.  What steps have you taken toward coding this?  If you help us see how far you've gotten, we can help you with next steps.

Comment: "i need to add a line extracts the text without the spaces" - add *to what*?  Please help us out by posting your current code.

Comment: how do I post code format? sorry I am a newb

Comment: To insert code, edit your post and indent the code 4 spaces.  If you're copying from vba, indent your code.  Then copy and paste.

Comment: added to original post :)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)-2))
```

[image]

This will remove any spaces *(if there are any)*.

**EDIT#1**

If there is material before and after the braces, use:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("[",A1)+1,FIND("]",A1,FIND("[",A1)+1)-(FIND("[",A1)+1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that there is additional text outside of the brackets

Comment: @B.Cole  see my **EDIT#1**

Comment: got it! I pasted my formula above; so I have the spaces string being extracted, but I want to add to the same vba script to also extract the ones with no spaces [12345]

Answer (score 0):

another possibility:

```
=TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,SEARCH("]",A1),LEN(A1),""),1,SEARCH("[",A1),""))
```

while, sticking to VBA you can use `Replace()` method of `Range` object and act on many cells simultaneously:

```
Sub ExtractText()

    With Range("X3:X8") ' reference wanted target range
        .Value2 = Range("A3:A8").Value2 ' have reference range values as corresponding column A range ones
        .Replace what:="*[", replacement:="", lookat:=xlPart 'get rid of text left of opening bracket (included)
        .Replace what:="]*", replacement:="", lookat:=xlPart 'get rid of text right of closing bracket (included)
        .Replace what:=" ", replacement:="", lookat:=xlPart ' trim
    End With

End Sub
```